# Сглаживание шрифтов в QPlainTextEdit

Tags: qt

Можно ли, а если можно, то с помощью чего реализовать сглаживание шрифтов в `QPlainTextEdit`?

Answer (score 1):

```
QPlainTextEdit edit;
QFont font = edit.font();
font.setStyleStrategy(QFont::PreferAntialias);
edit.setFont(font);
```